# Unity c# Image not appearing in UI canvas panel

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I have written a method `MakeCard()` that instantiates a card prefab (having a button) and adds an image to it through the script that uses an array of sprites but the image does not appear in the panel ("Card Pool") under which I'm setting its transform to. I have another method having the same code and it displays the card (with image) in some other panel (works perfectly fine). But the code isn't working for "Card Pool" panel. I am even displaying the index and the name of the card in logs to check if its fine and its fine. pls help!
EDIT: If i change the parent panel of a card from "Hand" to "Card Pool" it displays fine but if i instantiate the card and set its Parent as "Card Pool" it does not display. Hope this info makes any sense!

```
 public void MakeCard(int index)
 {
    print("Making Card..." + index);

    var cardCopy = Instantiate(cardObj, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), 
    Quaternion.identity);
    var newCard = cardCopy.GetComponent<Card>();
    newCard.SetFace(myData.shuffleIndex[index]);
    print(newCard.GetName());

    cardCopy.transform.SetParent(GameObject.Find("Card Pool").transform);
    cardCopy.GetComponent<Button>().interactable = false;
 }
```

the other code thats works perfectly fine is:

```
public void DistributeMyCards()
{

    for(int temp = myData.shuffleIndexToStartWith + 12; myData.shuffleIndexToStartWith < temp; myData.shuffleIndexToStartWith++)
    {
        //localHand.Add(myData.shuffleIndexToStartWith);

        Debug.Log("inside for: " + myData.shuffleIndexToStartWith);
        var cardCopy = Instantiate(cardObj, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
        var newCard = cardCopy.GetComponent<Card>();
        newCard.SetFace(myData.shuffleIndex[myData.shuffleIndexToStartWith]);

        cardCopy.transform.SetParent(GameObject.Find("Hand").transform);

        var owner = cardCopy.GetComponent<CardOwner>();
        owner.photonPlayer = PlayerNetwork.Instance.me;
        owner.setCardId(myData.shuffleIndexToStartWith);

        if (!PhotonNetwork.isMasterClient)
        {
            DisableThrowLocal(cardCopy);
        }

        localHand.Add(cardCopy);
    }
}
```

PS. Its a MP game but I guess that doesn't have anything to do with this problem.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the `ContentSizeFitter` component. Thats usually a staple for UIs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so I found the problem. I had to tick the `child controls size` (height and width) under horizontal layout group component attached to the panel just as the "Hand panel".